# How to restore BottomNavigationView state?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-support-design, bottomnavigationview

I'm wondering how one could restore the state of a BottomNavigationView (android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView).

I tried to call `bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(restoredItemId).setChecked(true);` but this does not result in a correct state inside BottomNavigationView, it only highlights the found item.

I also found below methods, but those don't seem to help much:

```
((BottomNavigationMenu) bottomNavigationView.getMenu()).savePresenterStates(state);
((BottomNavigationMenu) bottomNavigationView.getMenu()).saveActionViewStates(state);

((BottomNavigationMenu) bottomNavigationView.getMenu()).restorePresenterStates(state);
((BottomNavigationMenu) bottomNavigationView.getMenu()).restoreActionViewStates(state);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used the code below to select item programmatically:

```
View view = bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.menu_action_dashboard);
view.performClick();
```

Seems like it should work in your case.